# Recurring contribution every 4 weeks? Or 'First Friday of Month'?

Tags: recurring-contributions

I use civicrm for a union, and a lot of our members like paying their membership dues the day they get paid.

Is there a way to set up a recurring contribution to be something like 'once every 4 weeks, starting on x date, but not exceeding more than 1 a month?'  Or 'First Friday of the month' or '3rd weds of the month'?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What payment processor are you using? I believe the ability is dependent on which processor you are using.

Comment: Using Stripe for now.

Comment: I'd start here then https://drastikbydesign.com/blog-entry/civicrm-stripe-payment-processor  I am not positive that it recurring options are payment processor dependent so good luck.